# subquery in JPA/hibernate not returning correct result?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, subquery, jpql

I have a `oneToMany` association between Movie and actor Table and a `ManyToOne` association the reverse way.

I want to get the movie name for a given actor. In `SQL`, this query will be

```
SELECT m.name from Movie m INNER JOIN Actor a on a.movie_id=m.movie_id AND a.name='BRAD'
```

In `JPQL` work, same query will be written as

```
SELECT m.name from Movie m INNER JOIN m.actors act where act.name='BRAD'
```

This query is different than the pure SQL on described above.

I was hoping to perform something like this since each Movie object has a collection of Actors

```
SELECT m.name from Movie m, m.actors act where BRAD' EXISTS act.names
```

The above query grammar is wrong. But it conveys what I want to select for. How can I achieve this query without using JOIN and if possible without using subqueries.

In fact, I tried the following subquery version and it did not work either:

```
select m.name from Movie m Where EXISTS (SELECT act.movie FROM Actor act where act.name='Brad')
```

The above query returns all the Movies rows

Here are the relevant parts in my Entity:

```
    @Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(name="MOVIE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="MovieName")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="Date_Released")
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Actor> actors=new HashSet<>();

    public Movie(){}

    public Movie(String name, Date released){
        this.name=name;
        this.date=released;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Set<Actor> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    public void setActors(Set<Actor> actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return  id + " : " + name + " : " + date;
    }

    public void addActor(Actor a){
        getActors().add(a);
    }
}

    @Entity
public class Actor {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ACTOR_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="ACTOR_NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="ACTOR_MOVIE")
    private Movie movie;


    public Actor(){}

    public Actor(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " : " + movie.getName();
    }

}
```

Test Class here:

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

 Movie movie1 = new Movie("Mr and Mrs.Smith", new Date(2005, 6, 5));
    Actor actor3=new Actor("Brad");
    actor3.setMovie(movie1);
    Actor actor4=new Actor("Joe"); 
    actor4.setMovie(movie1);
    movie1.getActors().add(actor3);
    movie1.getActors().add(actor4);

    Movie movie = new Movie("Titanic", new Date(1997,12,19));
    Actor actor1=new Actor("Leo");
    Actor actor2=new Actor("Kate");
    actor1.setMovie(movie);
    actor2.setMovie(movie); 
    movie.getActors().add(actor1); 
    movie.getActors().add(actor2); 


   SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(movie);
    session.persist(movie1);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<String> bradMovies=session.createQuery("select m.name from Movie m, IN   (m.actors)actors"
            + " Where actors.name='BRAD'").list();
    System.out.println("bradMovies = "+ actorsFromMovies);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

}
}

**EDIT**:

I edited the code above to include entire code. Before it had only snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a HQL query that does not have any JOINs and Sub Queries:

```
Query q2 = session.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Movie m, IN (m.actors)actors 
WHERE actors.name = 'Brad'");
```

Also the below query in your question works but I am not clear why you don't want to use it.

```
SELECT m.name from Movie m INNER JOIN m.actors act where act.name='BRAD'
```

Comment: your first solution above is returning empty list. I am 100% there are entries that matches it since I just inserted. BTW,I dont want to use joins if it is not needed. Joins cause more performance issues.

Comment: @brainstorm, I have tested it in my machine and it worked, so I guess there is a difference what I have used and what you are using. Can you add more details on how your mapping looks like between entities and sample data in DB and the query generated by hibernate for my first HQL so I can see where is the difference. Also you said you don't want to use JOIN's or subqueries so what kind of query you are expecting because either JOIN or Subquery is needed to get your output.

Comment: please see edit above in the code. I have pasted the entire code.